# Environment variables in Windows Explorer shortcut under Favorites

Tags: windows, environment-variables, shortcut

I'm able to run this shortcut from my desktop w/o any issue. It's a link to OneDrive for Business. The shortcut launches Windows Explorer with my files and folders listed. (I plan to incorporate this into a login script so users can access their OneDrive for Business files from Windows Explorer Favorites w/o having to map a drive or use OneDriveSync.)

%windir%\explorer.exe /e,\mycompany-my.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\personal\%UserName%_mycompany_org\Documents

When I save this shortcut to c:\users\myusername\links (Windows Explorer Favorites shortcuts), and try to launch it from Favorites it launches Windows Explorer, but doesn't show my files.

If I first click Favorites at the top of Windows Explorer so my shortcuts are on the right side and then launch the shortcut it displays the files.

If I remove "%windir%\explorer.exe /e" the %username% saves as my username.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to resolve this: FastTrack Scripting and Powershell.

[FastTrack Scripting](http://www.fasttrackscript.com/) is a great scripting language we use for end user scripts and menus. This one line created the Favorites shortcut I needed:

```
CreateShortCut [UserProfileDir]\links\,OneDrive-ScriptTest,\\**mycompany**-my.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\personal\[UserName]_**companydomain_org**\Documents
```

Here is the powershell script I've verified works:

```
$destination = "c:\users\" + ${env:username} + "\links\"
$shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($destination + "OneDrive-Access.lnk") 
$shortcut.TargetPath = "\\**mycompany**-my.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\personal\" + "%username%" + "_**mycompanydomain_org**\Documents" 
$shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "%windir%" 
$shortcut.Description = "OneDrive-Access" 
$shortcut.Save()
```

*(items with ** need to be set for your o365 tenant)*